# Setting path in init.lua

Tags: neovim, path

One of my packages needs me to set up the PATH and one variable. In my vimscript code I had:

```
let $PATH.=':/usr/lib64/openjdk-11/bin/'
let $MYVIMRC='/home/luis/.config/nvim/init.vim'
```

But I can't figure out how to do this in an init.lua file. If I try to wrap around vim.cmd([[]]) the package still does not detect these changes.

Comment: Not sure what's happening, but maybe you can try to do it directly in command mode, like:  `:lua vim.cmd([[ let $PATH.='blablabla' ]])` and check it by `:echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Neovim has an API for getting and setting environment variables in Lua: [`vim.env`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.env).

Using `vim.env`, you can add to your path with this:

```lua
vim.env.PATH = vim.env.PATH .. ':/usr/lib64/openjdk-11/bin/'
```

In the same vein, you can set `$MYVIMRC` with:

```lua
vim.env.MYVIMRC = '/home/luis/.config/nvim/init.vim'
```